# Pulseaudio doesn't start at startup

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, startup

My problem may or may not be related to that in
[Problem with pulseaudio at startup (it doesn't start)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146026/problem-with-pulseaudio-at-startup-it-doesnt-start).

After booting, I have no sound, all the settings are greyed out in Settings | Sound. This is not a hardware problem, because my PC is dual boot and it works in Windows. I also get sound after I issue the command `pulseaudio --start`. But this is of course 'forgotten' next time the system starts.

I tried instead `systemctl --user enable pulseaudio`. This results in the message

```
Failed to enable unit: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Issuing `systemctl --user status` yields

```
Failed to read server status: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

I don't know how to nail this problem down further -- any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see that `pulseaudio` is running even though the `systemctl` status says it's not. My feeling is that systemd is not yet really used with `pulseaudio`.